# Each item clicked in combo box when clicked should connected to a specific function

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying to connect each item in a Combobox when clicked to connect to a specific function in python.

I have tried this: `self.comboBox_3.currentIndexChanged.connect()`

But I want to connect each item. For example if my Combo box has three animals such as dog, cat, horse. So when I select each item, example when I select dog it should run a particular Signal.

Comment: `self.comboBox_3.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda i: i == 0 and func())`.

Comment: I am trying to connect each item in combo box to a fuction or Slot. I  have tried this: self.comboBox_3.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda i: i == 0 and self.runsignals1) .but i want the Combo box with the each item changed  should connect to a Slot or fuction

Comment: `self.comboBox_3.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda i: i == 0 and func0()); self.comboBox_3.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda i: i == 1 and func1()); self.comboBox_3.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda i: i == 2 and func2())`.